# SpringMVC giving 404 returning a view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've got the following controller...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/userManagement")
public class UserManagementController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object home(Locale locale, Model model) {

        logger.info("User management view controller loaded...");

        return "userManagement";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/createUserView", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object createUser(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("create controller loaded...");
        return "createUser";
    }
```

My servlet-context is setup with the following values...

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

Now if I go to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/userManagement` then I get the view userManagement.jsp which is exactly what I want...

But if I go to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/userManagement/createUserView` I get a 404 error.

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/myapp/userManagement/createUserView"
```

What I don't see is why this would occur as I've set the requestMapping up exactly the same as above and in /WEB-INF/views I've got a createUser.jsp and userManagement.jsp

Is there anything I'm doing wrong with regards to serving up the views from spring mvc?

Thanks,

EDIT : web.xml added below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml 
    /WEB-INF/spring/security-app-context.xml
    /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

EDIT2:

Also, if I go directly to the address in the browser rather than using Ajax (going to myapp/userManagement/createUserView I get the error...

HTTP Status 404 - /myapp/WEB-INF/views/userManagement/createUserView.jsp so it appears to be looking at a directory too high (although the wrong filename too).

EDIT3.

Ok, it appears to be even when I do the following..

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/userManagement")
public class UserManagementController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public Object home(Locale locale, Model model) {

            logger.info("User management view controller loaded...");

            return "createUser";
        }
```

I'm still presented with the userManagement.jsp page, so it appears as if this return is not firing correctly, but I have no idea why.  The logger detail does still get fired to the console so it is actually reaching there, just something odd with the way springmvc is returning the JSP.

Comment: Can you please paste your application log file - there should be some mapping exception

Comment: sorry, editted the assessment thing, was just making it a bit more generic.  Nothing appears in my console as an exception, the error above was just from Firebug, which app log would you like?

Comment: There's something funny with your URLs.  It looks like you might have a dispatcher servlet mapped to /userManagement in your web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check for 2 things: 
1) Add breakpoint to controller or look at server log, check if request enters the method.
2) If 1st step is fine, check if jsp is present at correct path or the name of jsp is correct

**EDIT**

Wait, if you are using Ajax for request, your controller should have following requestMapping:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
  headers = "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest")
```

Else your ajax request will not get mapped and you will get 404.

**Side Note**
Can you change method return type from Object to String? See if that impacts anything?

Comment: Apologies, this was my fault in writing up the question, I've corrected the question.

Comment: 1.  The logger.info "create controller loaded" does always get called as it appears in my console.  2.  The file is definitely in the correct place.

Comment: @david99world   ok, can you test one thing, if you swap the 2 jsp return values and then call "/myapp/userManagement", does the jsp page, i.e., createUser.jsp load?

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, I changed myapp/userManagement to return "createUser" but it still returns the userManagement.jsp file instead, but the files are definitely there...

Comment: regarding the ajax, irrelevant to whether I use ajax or just browse to the page in a browser I still get the same problem.

Comment: @david99world - which Spring MVC version are you using? 3.x?

Comment: It was that I was returning an Object an not a String !! Thank you very much!  Changed return type to string, worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I think your web.xml mapping is incorrect, it should be:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

(Note `/*` in the url-pattern)

Comment: Ah, doing this made every page throw a 404 (even the main page)

Comment: Mapping a spring dispatcher to the root of the webapp context is a pain in the *.  You have to set up pass though for all the static content that isn't handled by spring's dispatcher.  The whole world makes more sense if you map them down a level.

Comment: That's a good point, I haven't set up Spring MVC in a while now.