# Spring JSP - One view returning 404

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jsp, controller

I have a controller class with a RequestMapping method. This method is not being rendered. I do not see any errors in my console. I am sure my request is being mapped correctly tried with some print statements. But the view is not rendering also there is no error in the log. I just get an HTTP 404 in browser. Not sure what is wrong when other views are being rendered properly. I have read the following question [SpringMVC giving 404 returning a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421239/springmvc-giving-404-returning-a-view)
but does not help.

Here is the request mapping method. Not sure what is wrong or how to debug it? All my jsp files are in one directory. I also have a public default constructor in my Controller. But something else could be wrong with my controller which I don't see yet. Here is the link to the more detailed code if you want more details.
https://github.com/C4G/V2V/blob/cbc4a8d9e904ab1f5bf47b9550a0879ccff33b01/src/controller/TestResultsController.java

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/editTestResultFormGenerator", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView editTestResultFormGenerator(HttpServletRequest request,
      Model model,
      @RequestParam(value="collectionNumber", required=false) Long collectionNumber,
      @RequestParam(value="collectionId", required=false) Long collectionId) {

    TestResultBackingForm form = new TestResultBackingForm();

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editTestResultForm");
    Map<String, Object> m = model.asMap();
    m.put("refreshUrl", getUrl(request));
    m.put("existingTestResult", false);
    if (collectionId != null) {
      form.setId(collectionId);
      TestResult testResult = testResultRepository.findTestResultByCollectionId(collectionId);
      if (testResult != null) {
        form = new TestResultBackingForm(testResult);
        m.put("existingTestResult", true);
      }
      else {
        form = new TestResultBackingForm();
      }
    }

    addEditSelectorOptions(m);
    m.put("editTestResultForm", form);
    m.put("refreshUrl", getUrl(request));
    // to ensure custom field names are displayed in the form
    m.put("testResultFields", utilController.getFormFieldsForForm("TestResult"));
    System.out.println(m);
    mv.addObject("model", m);
    return mv;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. With Eclipse autocomplete I chose the wrong ModelAndView class.

I should have chosen.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

whereas I chose

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
```

That explains it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `return mv;` at the end of your request handler method.

^ (Clearly wrong. Wasn't awake enough, heh.)

Edit after discussion: Something isn't quite right with that specific controller but it has nothing to do with the method's code. After looking at the code in your git repository, I can't see anything obvious and so recommend heavy logging/debugging to find out precisely where the problem is. Or simply not use that controller. :)

Comment: Mistake in the copied code. Sorry. Updated the question. I am returning mv. Otherwise there would be a compiler error.

Comment: Darn, was hoping for an easy one. :) Though thinking about it now, it wouldn't compile if you weren't returning so I should have known that was just a copy/paste error. Let's see...

Comment: Problem is the same pattern is working with other controllers but not this one. It used to work few days back before I started refactoring but this is a basic view. Project structure is very straightforward. So not sure why it is not working with this controller alone.

Comment: Why are you doing `form.setId(collectionId);` when you're going to reinstantiate that variable regardless of the test result?

Comment: If there is a problem with the jsp I should see a stacktrace at least along with Http 500 error. But I am getting a 404 error.

Comment: sure fixed what you mentioned. thanks for code review. but that does not solve the jsp problem :)

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking through for anything that didn't seem right as a potential culprit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20582/discussion-between-iamrohitbanga-and-nemesisx00)